# How To Do Recursive Observable Call in RxJava?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java, observable

I am quite new to [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) (and Reactive paradigm in general), so please bear with me.

Suppose I have this `News` and this nested `Comment` data structure:

```
public class News {
  public int id;
  public int[] commentIds; //only top level comments
  public News(int id, int[] commentIds) {
    this.id = id;
    this.commentIds = commentIds;
  }
}

public class Comment {
  public int id;
  public int parentId; //ID of parent News or parent comment
  public int[] childIds;
  public Comment(int id, int parentId, int[] childIds) {
    this.id = id;
    this.parentId = parentId;
    this.childIds = childIds;
  }
}
```

and suppose I have this API endpoint:

```
getComments(int commentId) //return Observable<Comment> for Comment with ID commentId
```

Now, let's assume:

```
getComments(1); //will return Comment(1, 99, [3,4])
getComments(2); //will return Comment(2, 99, [5,6])
getComments(3); //will return Comment(3, 1, [])
getComments(4); //will return Comment(4, 1, [])
getComments(5); //will return Comment(5, 2, [])
getComments(6); //will return Comment(6, 2, [])
```

**

### Now, if I have `News n = News(99, [1,2])`, how do I get all of its children comment recursively? i.e. to get comments with ID [1,2,3,4,5,6]?

**

I have searched and stumbled upon this: https://jkschneider.github.io/blog/2014/recursive-observables-with-rxjava.html

This is the recursion function:

```
public class FileRecursion {
    static Observable<File> listFiles(File f) {
        if(f.isDirectory())
            return Observable.from(f.listFiles()).flatMap(FileRecursion::listFiles);
        return Observable.just(f);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
          Observable.just(new File("/Users/joschneider/Desktop"))
                  .flatMap(FileRecursion::listFiles)
                  .subscribe(f -> System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath()));
    }
}
```

It shows an example on how to do recursive observable calls, but the inner function (`f.listFiles()`) is a blocking operation (doesn't return another Observable). In my case, the inner function (`getComments`) is a non-blocking function that returns another Observables. How do I do that?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You are mistaken - `listFiles` does return an `Observable`.

Comment: Hey, you're right! How could I not realize that? Ok, so how do I achieve this...hmm...

Comment: Oh, I mean the **inner function** `f.listFiles()`, that doesn't return observables, right? The one that returns observable is `FileRecursion::listFiles`. Or did I miss something, here?

Comment: You are right - that one is `File#listFiles` and it returns `File[]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does practically the same thing described in the article:

```
Observable<Comment> getInnerComments(Comment comment) {
    if (comment.childIds.length > 0)
        return Observable.merge(
                Observable.just(comment),
                Observable.from(comment.childIds)
                        .flatMap(id -> getComments(id))
                        .flatMap(this::getInnerComments));
    return Observable.just(comment);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    getComments(1)
          .flatMap(this::getInnerComments)
          .subscribe(c -> System.out.println(comment.toString()));
}
```

I start with the comment with id = 1, then I pass it to `getInnerComments()`. The `getInnerComments()` checks if the comment has children. If it does, it iterates over every child id (`Observable#from`) and loads every child with your `getComments(int)` API. Then every child is passed to the `getInnerComments()` to do the same procedure. If a comment doesn't have children, it is immediately returned using `Observable#just`.

This is pseudo-code and it wasn't tested, but you should get the idea.

---

Below is an example of how to get all comments and then aggregate them to one `List<Comment>`.

```
getNews(99)
        .flatMap(news -> Observable.from(news.commentIds))
        .flatMap(commentId -> getComments(commentId))
        .flatMap(comment -> getInnerComments(comment))
        .toList()
        .subscribe(commentList -> { });
```

Comment: Egor, that recursion only got me the **leaf** comment (i.e. comment that doesn't have any children). Looks like the non-leaf comment got subscribed inside the recursion function. Any idea?

Wait, I didn't see your updated answer. Let me contemplate first.

Comment: Hm, you are right, I haven't thought of that. I edited my answer - now `getInnerComments()` returns the comment passed to it and then does the other stuff.

Comment: @HoverPhoenix, wait a sec, I didn't understand your comment the first time I read it. Let me open up my IDE and try some stuff.

Comment: You rocks, Egor. It worked! The key point I'm missing is `flatMap` inside `flatMap`.
Moreover, now I understand why operator MERGE is needed! Thank you!
I have accepted your post as the answer.

Comment: Yep, I have just tested it and it works fine. Glad I could help you!.

Comment: Wait, the key point is not `flatMap` inside `flatMap` -_-". I can put the inner `flatMap` to the outside and achieve the same result. When I tried it the first time, I used `int[] commentIds` as the recursion parameter. I was just too focused on how to solve the `non-blocking function` part to realize that I was wrong since the beginning. Anyway, thanks again, Egor.